# How can I read the time metric for a product step using xperf

Tags: windows-7, performance, xperf

I have Windows Performance Kit installed on my Win7 machine [xperf.exe version is 4.8]. 
I am basically trying to measure the time taken to perform a specific set of steps on my s/w application [standalone].
I have recorded the trace when performing the steps on my application and trying to get time metric from the summary table.

I used the below commands

```
xperf -start mytrace -on PerfTrack, xperf -stop mytrace -d mytrace.etl
```

I only see providers PerfTrackMetaData and WinSATAssesment. Is it possible to tag my product/app for metrics? Please help

Answer (score 1):

The Apps must implement an [ETW provider](http://wychi.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/create-your-own-etw-provider-and-log-it-by-xperf/) and you must start this provider to get events logged.